# Peer fails to join the channel due to identity problems

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I've created a network based on 2 organizations under one two CA's (one normal, and one for TLS certificates). There's one orderer and one peer per organization.

I run the network as binaries on separate virtual machines.

After I create identities for organizations, I add the `signcert` directory from the CA admin to their respective `msp` directories as `admincerts`. I then enroll the identities on their respective machines, and add the `admincerts` directory. I create the ordererchannel genesis block and run the orderer binary. Next I generate `mychannel.tx` sign it with the peer's identity and submit the channel creation transaction (as far as I know, admin privilages are needed to successfully run `peer channel create`). Then, with the same identity, I try to join my peer to `mychannel` with `peer channel join`,and I get this error:

> Error: proposal failed (err: bad proposal response 500: access denied for [JoinChain][mychannel]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]])

Which is weird, because I could create the channel without problems, so the identity I'm using must be an admin. This happens on both peers. I would appreciate some input on the issue.

Comment: What do you have the the peer's local MSP `admincerts` directory?

Answer (score 0):

JoinChannel checks that the submitter is an admin of the peer itself.  Peer admin(s) is(are) stores in local MSP `admincerts` directory.